# jQuery.post changing the HTML of some special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, character-encoding, tinymce

Sample data in TinyMCE:

✓ and ☺ ✏ ✂

(HTML code of the above: `<p>&#10003; and &#9786; &#9999; &#9986;</p>`)

**Before: (working fine, getting same characters in saved document)**

```
function save_and_submit() {
    var tinyGenData = tinyMCE.get('webisoData').getContent();
    var tinyGenDataShow = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    opener.document.online_edit.command.value = 
    'save_online_edited_data';
    opener.document.online_edit.online_edited_data.value = tinyGenData;
    opener.document.online_edit.submit();
    setTimeout(saveMessageDelay,1000);
}
```

**After: (getting unexpected chars in saved document)**

```
function save_and_submit() {
var content = tinyMCE.get('webisoData').getContent();
jQuery.post("myscript1.pl",{
    online_edited_data: content,    
}).done(function (data) {
var content_img = data;
console.log(content_img); 
...
...
do some more work, call 1 more script, then save the document
...
});
```

`Console.log` output shows some strange HTML for the above characters which is

`<p>&Atilde;&cent;&Aring;&ldquo;&acirc;&euro;&oelig; and &Atilde;&cent;&Euml;&oelig;&Acirc;&ordm; &Atilde;&cent;&Aring;&ldquo;&Acirc; &Atilde;&cent;&Aring;&ldquo;&acirc;&euro;&scaron;</p>`

So the change is that I called a script for some extra work. I'm guessing it's something to do with `jQuery.post` which is changing the above special characters.

Any idea on what's the reason behind this and how can I stop it from changing HTML of the special chars?

PS: If I use `entity_encoding: numeric` in TinyMCE then everything works fine. But I don't get why it works fine in `Before` version then? There I didn't have any `entity_encoding` but still everything worked fine. So I think it's something to do with POST with jQuery.

Comment: HTML entities have little to do with character encodings other than allowing one to represent characters that are otherwise unavailable in the document's character encoding.  This likely has nothing to do with jQuery, AJAX, or anything like that; it's probably something that TinyMCE is doing.

Comment: @josh3736: You mean TinyMCE is interfering with `jQuery.post`?