# POST data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

> POST data will always be transmitted to the server using UTF-8 charset. -[jQuery.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Does this happen only when you use POST with jQuery (jQuery.post) or using `<form method=post>`?

Answer (score 2):

Content encoding of a form post is consistent with the declared document encoding. For example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

When a form is submitted, the default encoding is form-url-encoded.

An XHR request can override the setting:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset=utf-8;');
```

So to answer your question, it is possible to have a form submission in iso-8859-1, and yet the Ajax call uses utf-8. Please avoid such situation, or your server side code will get messy.

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

In HTML, the charset can be set by setting the `accept-charset` attribute on the form. If not set or the given values are not valid, the user agent defaults to the document's charset then to UTF-8. [jQuery does it via setting the `Content-Type` header on the request.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/0d68b7877f761264bfe4950e4df156b854925a6b/src/ajax.js#L305)

#### Longer answer w/ sources

All HTML forms may have the attribute `accept-charset` which, as the HTML spec says:

> The `accept-charset` attribute gives the character encodings that are to
>   be used for the submission. If specified, the value must be an ordered
>   set of unique space-separated tokens that are ASCII case-insensitive,
>   and each token must be an ASCII case-insensitive match for one of the
>   labels of an ASCII-compatible character encoding.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/forms.html#the-form-element), two paragraphs below the big blue thingy.

You may also be interested in §4.10.22.5 *Selecting a form submission encoding*, emphasis mine:

> If the user agent is to pick an encoding for a form, optionally with
>   an allow non-ASCII-compatible encodings flag set, it must run the
>   following substeps:
>
> 1. Let input be the value of the form element's accept-charset attribute.
> 2. Let candidate encoding labels be the result of splitting input on
>      spaces.
> 3. Let candidate encodings be an empty list of character encodings.
> 4. For each token in candidate encoding labels in turn (in the order in
>      which they were found in input), get an encoding for the token and, if
>      this does not result in failure, append the encoding to candidate
>      encodings.
> 5. If the allow non-ASCII-compatible encodings flag is not set, remove
>      any encodings that are not ASCII-compatible character encodings from
>      candidate encodings.
> 6. **If candidate encodings is empty, return UTF-8 and abort these steps.**
> 7. Each character encoding in candidate encodings can represent a finite
>      number of characters. (For example, UTF-8 can represent all 1.1
>      million or so Unicode code points, while Windows-1252 can only
>      represent 256.)
>
>    For each encoding in candidate encodings, determine how many of the
>      characters in the names and values of the entries in the form data set
>      the encoding can represent (without ignoring duplicates). Let max be
>      the highest such count. (For UTF-8, max would equal the number of
>      characters in the names and values of the entries in the form data
>      set.)
>
>    Return the first encoding in candidate encodings that can encode max
>      characters in the names and values of the entries in the form data
>      set.

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/forms.html#selecting-a-form-submission-encoding)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. But I'm not submitting the form, I'm calling the script like this `jQuery.post("myscript.pl", {
                online_edited_data: content,}).done(function(data){....`. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179247/jquery-post-changing-the-html-of-some-special-characters

Comment: What relationship should this answer have to the other question? How should the two questions relate?